# wp_set_object_terms not accepting variable array

Tags: array, terms

I am trying to use the following command:

```
wp_set_object_terms( $myID, $myissuearray, 'my_issues', true );
```

But for some reason, it won't accept my variable array.

That array, `$myissuearray`, using `error_log(print_r($myissuearray,true))` outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 9
    [1] => 10
    [2] => 77
    [3] => 12
)
```

Which sure looks like a valid array to me.

If on the other hand, I don't use my variable and set the issue array by hand in the command to something like:

```
wp_set_object_terms( $myID, array(9,10,77,12), 'my_issues', true );
```

the command works and the terms are set. I am stumped as to what I am doing wrong. Why won't this command accept my variable array??

Comment: how are you setting `$myissuearray`? also can you `var_dump` instead of `print_r` and show the result?

Comment: I JUST did that, and I notice they are strings, so I think that solves the mystery thanks. Now to figure out how to convert my string array to integers...

Comment: nice, please consider deleting the question or answering yourself

Comment: I will as soon as I figure out the rest, thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so it turned out that my array was an array of strings somehow, which using var_dump (instead of print_r) revealed. Then I needed to convert my array to int values, which I did thus:

```
$myissuearrayINT = array_map('intval', $myissuearray);
```

And now, when I do the following it works as expected:

```
wp_set_object_terms( $myID, $myissuearrayINT, 'my_issues', true );
```

Hope this helps someone else out there...